# How to remove the transactions from Google Analytics Ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics

I have made several test orders and they are tracked successfully by Google Analytics Ecommerce. For now, I want to remove one of the orders and I take the advice from http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75012 , here's the snippet I composed http://gist.github.com/471505 , I saved it in a .html file and opened it with Firefox, waited for more than 24 hours, and I found the transaction is still there, it's not been removed, any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To reverse an order or transaction, you will create and load a duplicate receipt page that contains negative values for transaction total, tax, shipping, and item quantity.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_gas.create(['UA-XXXXX-X', 't1']);

_gas.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234', // order ID - required
    'Store name', // store / affiliate name
    '-28.28', // price without TAXes and shipping - required
    '-1.29', // TAX
    '-15.00', // shipping
    'Carlisle', // city
    'Cumbria', // state
    'UK' // country
]);

_gas.push(['_addItem',
    '1234', // order ID - for association with order - required
    'DD44', // SKU/code - required
    'Teddy bear', // product name
    'Pink', // category / variant
    '28.28', // unit price - required
    '-1' // amount - required
]);

_gas.push(['_trackTrans']);
</script>
```

See [Reverse an Ecommerce transaction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en) and [Remove e-commerce transactions from Google Analytics](http://www.ga-script.org/en/posts/2012/05/remove-e-commerce-transactions-from-google-analytics)

Answer (score 0):

Reread carefully the article from http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75012, and you'll find the following note:

> Note that you will still be able to
>   see the actual transaction and the
>   duplicate negative transaction when
>   you select the day on which these
>   transactions were recorded. However,
>   when you select a date range that
>   includes both the original and the
>   negative transaction, the transaction
>   will not be shown in the report. The
>   negative item quantity should result
>   in the same effect in the products
>   reports.

Comment: @codesnake, the problem is I can not see the duplicate negative transaction from the report, I can only see the initial positive one

Comment: the link is dead now, the alternative answer is http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1037443 , but the note quoted has been removed

Comment: @codesnake,while searching from transaction actual date to today date for reports.It shows only the neagative transaction and the revenue is correct.
But when i searched with today date.It shows negative transaction with double the amount and quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the question, but....

I was looking for to do the same thing and just found this post, so I have nothing original to offer. However, as to why the negative transaction is not showing up in GA, perhaps you have a filter that is ignoring your machine? For example, my home IP address is ignored by GA so the above gist presumably wouldn't work for me either, unless I left the house.

A long shot, but a possibility.